# jquery - picture element swap in ie 11

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer-11

Hi I am using a piece of jquery to swap background images via the picture element depending on viewport width. It works in mst browser except ie 11.

Does anyone have an idea why? Help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
function setImgBackground(){
$('.banner-item').each( function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var picture = $this.find('picture').get(0);
  var src = picture.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].currentSrc;

  $(this).css({
      'background-image':'url('+src+')'
  });
 });
}


<ul class="bannerContainer">
<li class="banner-item full about">
<picture>
  <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1664x412?
 text=desktop_1664x412" media="(min-width: 960px)">
    <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/768x500?text=tablet_768x500"  media="(min-width: 768px)">
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/414x500?text=mobile_414x500"  media="(min-width: 0px)">
  <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
  <img alt="product" class="mobileBg">
</picture>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here is a link to the [codepen](https://codepen.io/struthy/pen/YxeGer)

Comment: IE 11 does not really support the `picture` element yet. Have you checked whether your attempts to select elements are actually successful in IE …?

Comment: `<!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->` - that should be `<video>` for the starting comment, not `</video>` ...

Comment: thanks guys. I am going to go another way with this so dont waste any time on it. thanks again.